# robot framework: exception handling

Tags: testing, robotframework

Is it possible to handle exceptions from the test case?  I have 2 kinds of failure I want to track: a test failed to run, and a test ran but received the wrong output. If I need to raise an exception to fail my test, how can I distinguish between the two failure types? So say I have the following:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Case 1
    Login            1.2.3.4    user    pass
    Check Log For    this log line
```

If I can't log in, then the `Login` Keyword would raise an `ExecutionError`. If the log file doesn't exist, I would also get an `ExecutionError`. But if the log file does exist and the line isn't in the log, I should get an `OutputError`.

I may want to immediately fail the test on an `ExecutionError`, since it means my test did not run and there is some issue that needs to be fixed in the environment or with the test case.  But on an `OutputError`, I may want to continue the test. It may only refer to a single piece of output and the test may be valuable to continue to check the rest of the output.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robot has several keywords for dealing with errors, such as [Run keyword and ignore error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error) which can be used to run another keyword that might fail. From the documentation:

> This keyword returns two values, so that the first is either string
>   PASS or FAIL, depending on the status of the executed keyword. The
>   second value is either the return value of the keyword or the received
>   error message. See Run Keyword And Return Status If you are only
>   interested in the execution status.

That being said, it might be easier to write a python-based keyword which calls your Login keyword, since it will be easier to deal with multiple exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
${err_msg}=  Run Keyword And Expect Error  *  <Your keyword>
Should Not Be Empty  ${err_msg}
```

There are couple of different variations you could try like
`Run Keyword And Continue On Failure`, `Run Keyword And Expect Error`, `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` for the first statement above.

Option for the second statement above are `Should Be Equal As Strings`, `Should Contain`, `Should Match`.

You can explore more on [Robot keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error)